# timestamp and datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table with two columns first column is a (currentdate)timestamp and the other one is a (dateReturn)datetime column.i i need to get the difference between currentdate and dateReturn from number of days.is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Contrary to popular belief (and the name itself), a `timestamp` column *is not actually related to time*.

***Disclaimer**: This answer is specific to Sql Server (as per the tags of the question), other database engines might have different implementations here.**

Instead it is a 64-bit number that steadily increases. The value of the number is shared between all tables in a single database that has such a timestamp column. In other words, if you have two such tables, modify a row in one, and modify a row in the other, the value of the timestamp in the first table would be X, and in the second table would be X+1.

[as per the documentation of timestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.90).aspx):

> Each database has a counter that is incremented for each insert or update operation that is performed on a table that contains a timestamp column within the database. This counter is the database timestamp. This tracks a relative time within a database, not an actual time that can be associated with a clock.

As such, the value is not related to the actual date and/or time the row was inserted or last modified, and can not be converted to such a date/time in any way.

The only purpose of a `timestamp` column is to have something unique, that is guaranteed to be  increasing. Since the value is 64 bit, you will have access to `18 446 744 073 709 551 616` operations which require a `timestamp` column before the value resets. If you have a database that can handle a million such operations every second, you will still have to wait around 584 554 years before the value resets, so I would say it meets the uniqueness requirements.

Comment: Most of the time, a timestamp column means a column with type "datetime" and name "timestamp".  Columns with type "timestmap" are relatively rare.

Comment: In this case, he specifically said one column was a datetime, and the other a timestamp.

Comment: In other words, the name `currentdate`, is a bit of a misnomer. If the field is supposed to hold the date and time of the last modification (or initial insert), then `timestamp` is the wrong data type, and a datetime column and a trigger or similar is more appropriate.

Comment: In MySQL, timestamp does store the actual datetime. It store datetime in UTC format. In SQL it is entirely different thing as the answer says http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html.

Comment: And yet the tag says sql-server.

Answer (score 4):

The [timestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) data type in sql server does not store a date or time. It is more of a version maintaining column which is updated every time the row is updated. So you should reconsider the data type of this column

Answer (score -1):

If your column has the (relatively rare) [`timestamp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) type,  Lasse V. Karlsen's answer is right.

If both columns have the `datetime` type, you can:

```
select  datediff(day, dateReturn, currentdate)
from    YourTable
```

See the [datediff function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258269%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).