# SQL Server 2008 timestamp data type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

At present I have a column with datatype `datetime` with default constraint. Now I want to alter as a data type as time stamp.

```
alter table tblname
alter column date_modified timestamp not null
```

My original requirement is whenever I update a record the column called `date_modified` should update with recent time .

This is same functionality which is working in MYSQL with datatype `TIMESTAMP` and default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

How can I perform in this in SQL Server 2008??

Comment: To those who posted answers - I think he's asking how to mimic the MySQL Timestamp in MS SQL. The only way I know is with a Trigger (hopefully someone knows a more graceful solution)

Comment: You can do it using a trigger http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: I think i dont care what he thinks. I am not in the business of reading his mind. I answer the question he asks. And the answers below are answering the question he asis. Learning what questions to ask - and now to at least use the doucmentation once for 30 seconds when you have a problem - is what separates script kiddies from people knowing how to program. Sorry. If he wants another question answered, he can ask it. It is not like asking questions costs money.

Comment: possible duplicate of [timestamp and datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698707/timestamp-and-datetime)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Timestamp in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html) and [timestamp in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) is not the same thing. Keep your `datetime`and add an `after update` trigger that updates `date_modified` with `getdate()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I like your way of answering.

Comment: Thank you @Mikael. this is how I was doing first! Was trying to use the sql timestamp instead of datetime! Now I read that the sql `timestamp` is neither the UNIX `timestamp` nor the T-SQL `timestamp`. I think I have to keep working with `datetime`. Thank u very much

Comment: Now I read here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631%28v=sql.80%29.aspx that the sql `timestamp` neither is  the UNIX `timestamp` nor the T-SQL `timestamp`. I think I have to keep working with `datetime`. Thank u very much

Answer (score 4):

Did you check what the [TIMESTAMP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms182776%28SQL.90%29.aspx) type actually is in SQL Server? It's different from the [TIMESTAMP type in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html). The documentation says:

> Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database

So there's no way to set it to "the current time"