# What is the difference between TimeStamp and DateTime in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, timestamp, sqldatatypes

In SQL Server, there is the TimeStamp type, when should I use it or not instead of simply DateTime?

What is use for TimeStamp? I've heard it is to guarantee that the datetime won't be changed, like a stamp. Is it?

Comment: This could probably be closed as a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698707/timestamp-and-datetime), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665548/sql-server-2008-timestamp-data-type), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154742/how-do-i-get-date-time-information-from-a-timestamp-column)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**timestamp** is automatically generated and unique.  This is deprecated.

**Note from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)**

> The timestamp syntax is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a
>   future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in
>   new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently
>   use this feature.

**datetime** is a data type that handles dates and times

Comment: Why are they going to remove it?

Comment: Probably because it is a synonym for rowversion.